# Matplotlib - scatter on top of regular plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, overlay, scatter

I have this:

```
 fig = plt.subplot2grid((count, count), (i, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=count)
 fig.plot(x, y, label='trup')
```

I also want to scatter another time series, on the same figure, with the same axes and scale, something like

```
fig.scatter(x2, y2, label='scatter')
```

How do I do this?

Edit: This works, but I am getting 2 different pairs of axes:

```
fig = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=count)
fig.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter(u, v)
```

How do I make sure they are on the same exact axis?

Comment: Tried, did not work, if you're not willing too help, might as well make yourself scarce.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=matplotlib+overlay+scatter+on+top+of+plot&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I also attempted something like
 ax2 = plt.gca().twinx()
    ax2.
but that created different axis that was not necessarily alligned with the original.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you had in mind, i.e. type it out in terms of my notation from above?

Comment: I work in notebook, so there's no error trace, nor a figure.

Comment: What actually happens in the first two calls of fig.scatter and fig.plot? The way you've written it, it should work.

Comment: I am getting different axes.

Comment: Can you paste an image of what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set [`plt.hold(True)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hold)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10)
u = np.arange(0, 10)

plt.hold(True)
plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
plt.plot(x,x)
plt.scatter(u, u[::-1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Above is the `pyplot` version.  You can also plot directly to the axes of your choice, so the following will give the same plot as above:

```
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
ax.plot(x,x)
ax.scatter(u, u[::-1])
```

Comment: Stupid question, but why is this required? For ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111), you can add as many scatter/plots without plt.hold(True)? The underlying default setting of hold changes for subplot2grid?

Comment: @jonnybazookatone the status `hold` get's confused when you mix the object-oriented interface with the `pyplot` interface. In other words, `pyplot` commands will always try to make a new `figure`/`axes` unless you tell it not to. [soapbox]This is exactly why `pyplot` should be avoided when methods of the `axes` objects are so easily accessible.[/soapbox]

Comment: @PaulH Yes, this makes sense. But from his first post, he does indeed access the object form as it noted in the solution. Only on his second attempt does he mix the objects and direct calls of pyplot. So, his unedited code should work fine.

Comment: @jonnybazookatone: whether the original solution would work depends on the "hold state" since the OP never directly plots to the axes (eg, by using an axes object), and since the original approach didn't work, apparently, hold was False.  The hold state can be set elsewhere in the code, or in the matplotlibrc file.

Comment: Weird. I would have thought the default setting upon installation of matplotlib would be standard for all builds and versions. Given he knew nothing of it, I don't see him editing the matplotlibrc file. Fair enough.